# Android Campaign Measurement Not Working

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play

Ok, I have been all over looking for an answer as to why my Google Play campaign measurement is not working.  I am not getting any data in my Analytics account.  Here is what I have:

Google Play Services version 6171000 imported into my project and added as a reference.

Google Play App version 5.0.38 on my testing device

In my res\xml\global_tracker.xml file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="https://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:ignore="TypographyDashes">

    <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
    <string name="ga_trackingId">MY-TRACKING-ID</string>

    <bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>
    <!-- Enable automatic activity tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">false</bool>

    <!-- Enable automatic exception tracking -->
    <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

</resources>
```

In my Manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

and within `<application>` I have:

```
<!-- Used for Google Play Store Campaign Measurement -->
<service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService" />

<receiver
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource"
    android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
```

Now, I did the getTracker method in my extended Application class suggested by the Analytics setup document, but I don't think that is needed for just the app download tracking.  Please correct me if I'm wrong here and I will post the code I have for that as well.

To test I have tried running

```
adb shell am broadcast -a com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER -n com.my.package/com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver --es "referrer" "utm_source=testSource&utm_medium=testMedium&utm_term=testTerm&utm_content=testContent&utm_campaign=testCampaign"
```

and I get a "Broadcast completed: result=0"
and then open my app on my device and I get nothing in the logs about campaign.  Although I did read that this is not the proper way to test when using V4.

I've also packaged my app and uploaded to the Beta section of my store listing.  While logged into one of my beta tester accounts, I opened the following in my browser and downloaded the app.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.package&referrer=utm_source%3DTestSite%26utm_medium%3DsideBanner%26utm_term%3DTestTerm%26utm_content%3DTestContent%26utm_campaign%3DtestCampaign

This I would expect to yield some sort of results in the Acquisition->Google Play Referral section of my Analytics account and have something to do with testCampaign.  I do not see anything in my account not even after 24 hours (not sure that's still required but I remember it used to be for GA).

If anyone knows of a piece that I'm missing or why it would not be showing up in my account, please point me in the right direction.  Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Here is my tracker code in my extended Application Class:

```
private static final String TRACKER_TAG = "GA Tracker";
HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER // Tracker used only in this app.
}

synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerEnum) {
    Log.d(TRACKER_TAG, "Getting GA tracker");
    if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerEnum)) {
        Log.d(TRACKER_TAG, "Creating new GA tracker");
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        mTrackers.put(trackerEnum, t);
    }
    return mTrackers.get(trackerEnum);
  }
```

Comment: "I did the getTracker method in my extended Application" Post your GA integration code. Also, does GA work in general?

Comment: Your global tracker shows debug mode to be true , did you change it in the release ?

Comment: I did not change it in the release, but does that really make the difference?  I assumed that just disabled any debug features.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already did it but,

did you set your Tracking ID at >>>>>  `<string name="ga_trackingId">MY-TRACKING-ID</string>` ?

Comment: Yes, I set it, but purposefully changed it to post the question.